# Conditional matching in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying extract some information from the below given string

```
>>> st = '''
... <!-- info mp3 here -->
...                             192 kbps<br />2:41<br />3.71 mb  </div>
... <!-- info mp3 here -->
...                             3.49 mb  </div>
... <!-- info mp3 here -->
...                             128 kbps<br />3:31<br />3.3 mb   </div>
... '''
>>>
```

Now when I use the below regex my output is

```
>>> p = re.findall(r'<!-- info mp3 here -->\s+(.*?)<br />(.*?)<br />(.*?)\s+</div>',st)
>>> p
[('192 kbps', '2:41', '3.71 mb'), ('128 kbps', '3:31', '3.3 mb')]
```

but my required output is

```
[('192 kbps', '2:41', '3.71 mb'),(None,None,'3.49mb'), ('128 kbps', '3:31', '3.3 mb')]
```

So, my question is how do I change my above `regex` to match all the conditions.I believe my current regex is strictly dependent on `<br />` tags so how do I make it conditional on that.

I know I should not be using regex to parse html but currently this is the most appropriate way for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will work, though I wonder if there's not a more elegant solution. You can certainly combine the list comprehensions into one line, but I think that makes the code less clear overall. At least this way you'll be able to follow what you did three months from now...

```
st = '''
<!-- info mp3 here -->
                            192 kbps<br />2:41<br />3.71 mb  </div>
<!-- info mp3 here -->
                            3.49 mb  </div>
<!-- info mp3 here -->
                            128 kbps<br />3:31<br />3.3 mb   </div>
'''

p = re.findall(r'<!-- info mp3 here -->\s+(.*?)\s+</div>',st)
p2 = [row.split('<br />') for row in p]
p3 = [[None]*(3 - len(row)) + row for row in p2]

>>> p3
[['192 kbps', '2:41', '3.71 mb'], [None, None, '3.49 mb'], ['128 kbps', '3:31', '3.3 mb']]
```

And, depending on the variability in your string, you may want to write a more generic cleaning function that strips, cases, whatever, and map it to each item you pull out.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex solution that works by being a bit more specific. I'm not sure this is preferable to [Karmel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10744878/577088)'s answer, but I figured I'd answer the question as asked. Instead of returning `None`, the first two optional groups return the empty string `''`, which I think is probably close enough.

Note the nested group structure. The first two outer groups are optional, but the `<br />` tag is required for them to match. That way, if there are fewer than two `<br />` tags, the last item doesn't match until the end:

```
rx = r'''<!--\ info\ mp3\ here\ -->\s+   # verbose mode; escape literal spaces
         (?:                             # outer non-capturing group  
            ([^<>]*)                     # inner capturing group without <>
            (?:<br\ />)                  # inner non-capturing group matching br
         )?                              # whole outer group is optional
         (?:                             
            ([^<>]*)                     # all same as above
            (?:<br\ />)                
         )?
         (?:                             # outer non-capturing group
            (.*?)                        # non-greedy wildcard match
            (?:\s+</div>)                # inner non-capturing group matching div
         )'''                            # final group is not optional
```

Tested:

```
>>> re.findall(rx, st, re.VERBOSE)
[('192 kbps', '2:41', '3.71 mb'), 
 ('', '', '3.49 mb'), 
 ('128 kbps', '3:31', '3.3 mb')]
```

Note the `re.VERBOSE` flag, which is necessary unless you remove all the whitespace and comments above.